# How to delete anonymous users with their docs in firebase?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

For all new users, I create some docs using the firebase function onCreate. If the user is deleted, then onDelete function is triggered and all his docs are removed. It's working, but not for anonymous users when I try to delete them calling another function with:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

export default async (data: any, context: functions.https.CallableContext) => {
  try {
    const contextUid = context.auth?.uid;

    if (!contextUid) {
      return;
    }

    const auth = admin.auth();
    const currentUser = await auth.getUser(contextUid);
    const list = await auth.listUsers();

    if (!(currentUser?.customClaims?.role === 'admin')) {
      return;
    }

    if (!(list && list.users.length > 0)) {
      return;
    }

    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const uids = list.users
      .filter((user) => {
        if (user?.metadata?.lastRefreshTime) {
          const diffInMs = now - new Date(user?.metadata?.lastRefreshTime).getTime();
          const diffInDays = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
          return !user.email && !user.emailVerified && diffInDays > 2;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      })
      .map((user) => user.uid);
    return auth.deleteUsers(uids);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error);
  }
};
```

index.ts

```
export const deleteAnonymous = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return (await import('./fn/deleteAnonymousOnCall')).default(data, context);
});
```

Anonymous users are deleted, but not with their docs in firebase collections. How can I fix it?

Comment: If I correctly understand you, you have a Cloud Function that is triggered when a user is deleted. This CF works correctly when it is a non-anonymous user and does not work for an anonymous user. Is that right? Is the function triggered for an anonymous user but generates an error OR the function is not even triggered?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec functions.auth.user().onDelete if triggered if user is deleted manually in firebase console (anonymous or not, nvm). In that onDelete handler I delete all docs that are related to the deleted user. It's ok. But I need to delete all anonymous users using firebase function (not doing this manually in firebase console). So I added a function with a code above to find all anonymous users and delete them. Unfortunately  when users are deleted using firebase function, code from functions.auth.user().onDelete() is not executed.

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly delete the users with the Cloud Function? A very common mistake with Cloud Functions is to incorrectly manage their life cycle, which generates some erratic behaviour. Can you pls share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function that delete the users?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Sure, updated the code

Comment: Seems like an issue on how you are filtering the anonymus users, when you get the list of users are you receiving them all, or is that list empty?